# Why Acumatica ERP PX.DataSource give rendering error at design view?

Tags: acumatica, erp

I started using Acumatica ERP framework to create a sample application. I follow the steps provided in training document. By following the steps i added a ListView maintenance page.

The newly created page has PX.DataSource control created by acumatica framework. But this control has one error message with it i.e. "Error Rending Control - usrCaption". I attached the screenshot of this error.

[image: Error in rendering control]

I reinstalled framework many time but still same issue occurred to me. I opened my project on other machines and it's working fine. and also projects created on other machines that are working fine on source machine also giving same error on my machine.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please check this article about asking questions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question by adding details.

Comment: Yes, it is a known issue that these controls will show this errors. It's best if you either edit the page in code or using the customization project editor (web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why Acumatica ERP PX.DataSource give rendering error at design view?

Usually this occurs because the template are lagging behind in terms of maintenance and aren't 100% compatible with all possible Visual Studio deployment (especially the latest versions).

The templates are very rarely used and since the `Customization Project Editor` has all the same features and more this is the one most users are using and the focus is put on maintaining this one before the Visual Studio templates.

It's unfortunate that the T100 training documents focus on these. Support regarding the templates is always originating from T100 training since they aren't very useful besides that. I would prefer the training direct new user to the Customization Project Editor instead because as far as I know it is what everybody uses and the only one that is always up to date.